# excel plot with Y non numerical values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to make a "scatter straight lines and markers" plot with non numerical value for Y axis.
I'm not able to use non numerical index as `y` value.

Here is how my data looks like:

[image: Data]

What I did so far is using numerical "fake" label to plot what I want.

Here is how my plot looks like right now:

[image: Plot]

What should I do to use the non numerical data for the Y axis?

[image: Here is how it should looks like]

Comment: This seems paradoxical: by definition, graphs represent numerical data. Convert the non-numerical data to numerical data is my suggestion. If not, can you show us what the chart should look like?

Comment: it should looks like this

Comment: Look into label maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do.  All you need is an XY/Scatter Chart and a helper column.  Use the helper column to assign a value to each categorical item.  In your case, the values could run from 1-14.  These values will also determine the hierarchy that they're plotted, so you can be as creative as you'd like.  Once you have the helper column, plot that as your Y series values and your data series is plotted.  All the rest is formatting.  To get your axis labels, I'd recommend an additional helper column to create a second series to replace your vertical axis.

**DATA**

1. Rename your current second data column "Y Label"
2. Add a helper column "Y", with values 1,2,3,...n of your series.
3. Add another helper column "X Label", with values of -3 (or whatever the minimum value for your horizontal axis will be) for each of your rows of data.
4. And, as a best practice (but not required), convert your data to a Table.

[image: data table]

**CHART**

1. Create a new, blank XY/Scatter Chart
2. Add 2 data series to your chart.  One is your data comprised of columns "X" and "Y". The second is "Y" and "X Label"

[image: basic chart]

Everything else is formatting.

1. Select your Labels series and Add Data Labels
2. Format Data Labels and under Label Options:

   1. Select Value From Cells and for the Data Label Range use your "Y Label" data column
   2. Also, de-select Y Value and Show Leader Lines
   3. Finally change Label Position to Left

[image: label axis]

Final Touches:

1. Vertical Axis

   1. Change min value to 0 and max value to 15 (or 1 less than your min value and 1 greater than your max value, to create visual "margins" around your series)
   2. Select Values in reverse order (your data will read top to bottom)
   3. Labels, select Label Position "None" (you've replaced them with your label series)
   4. Select Horizontal Axis crosses at Maximum axis value (to move the axis to the bottom of the chart, since we reversed Y axis values)
2. Horizontal Axis

   1. Change min value to -3 and max value to 3 and major units to 1 and minor units to 0.5  (matches values in your demo)
3. "X Label" Series

   1. Format Markers to "None" and Lines to "No Line"

[image: final format]